# How to set charset when using EsSparkSQL.esDF API to reading from elasticsearch on spark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

When I using Elasticsearch-Spark API to reading data from elasticsearch on Spark, I encountered charset issue, because the spark cluster don't use utf-8 as default.

I want to know where can set the charset as utf-8, in my coding as below:

```
val sqlc = new SQLContext(new SparkContext(conf))
val df = EsSparkSQL.esDF(sqlc, resource).cache()
```

- SparkContext?
- SQLContext?
- EsSparkSQL?
- to add the third parameter cfg: Map[String, String]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In actually, to find the way from coding either spark or elasticsearch is not correct, it's a platform question, so we can solve it from platform or environment.

When we submit the job to cluster, adding the below params after `"--master" yarn-cluster` could solve the issue:

```
"--master" yarn-cluster

"--conf" "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8"

"--conf" "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8"
```